# ¿Cómo encontrar el código del kernel en macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos

Estoy aprendiendo más de Linux y me gustaría ver el código del Kernel de mi sistema.

Uso macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede encontrar el código del kernel con este path en macOS Mojave versión 10.14.6.

`/System/Library/Kernels`